# What is the best way to count the missing/default value rows of a column in Hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql

```
select 
count(COLUMN_A is null or COLUMN_A like '0*') as num_miss_rows,
count(*) as num_total_rows
from tableX;
```

is not working. Because count(expr) function increments on any expr returns non-null value even 0.

I want to compute num_miss_rows/num_total_rows, for many columns.

What is the best way to do this counting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a case inside a sum (also should be `like 0%` not `like 0*`):

```
select 
sum(case when COLUMN_A is null or COLUMN_A like '0%' then 1 end) as num_miss_rows,
count(*) as num_total_rows
from tableX;
```

Comment: Figured this out too. :) In fact, I want to match repeated character of '0' in zero or more times. % matches any characters. I used rlike "^0*$".